# Find and replace "=" for "=" until the last worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sum

I am using a code that sums values based upon the font color. It works great, but for some reason all of the equations will turn to #N/A randomly and then I have to do a find and replace "=" for "=" to restore the sums. I share the file with my supervisors and I would like to either find a way to prevent the #N/A from replacing the formula or have a code that will allow me to create a button to run the find and replace to restore the sums. When I use a find and replace code, it loops endlessly. Is there a way to have it end on the last worksheet? Or only run through the workbook once at a time.

Here is the sum code I am using:

```
Function SumCellsByFontColor(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range)
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range
    Dim sumRes
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
    Application.Volatile
    sumRes = 0
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Font.Color
    For Each cellCurrent In rData
        If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Font.Color Then
            sumRes = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cellCurrent, sumRes)
        End If
    Next cellCurrent
 
    SumCellsByFontColor = sumRes
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  End Function
  Sub Sumcellsbyfont()

  End Sub
```

Here is the find and replace code that I have been trying out:

```
 Sub FindReplaceAll()

  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Dim fnd As Variant
  Dim rplc As Variant

   fnd = "="
rplc = "="

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
     LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

   Next sht

   End Sub
```

I am new to using VBA, but I hope to make this work as summing by the font color will save me the trouble of having to exclude values from a regular sum formula as I make changes. I am working with about 15 sheets per workbook.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is it just a matter of recalculating the sheet? Is it on manual calcs?

Comment: Five `Application` calls seems weird for a 15 lines function called from an Excel workbook. I would definitely not advice the use of `Application.Volatile` to a beginner.

Comment: My guess is the the function is erroring and the calcs are being left as manual, till it is run again.  Remove the calculation and screenupdating lines.  Then watch when the formula errors and find out why.  Make sure the calcs are set to automatic.

Comment: Not sure that it may be the root of the problem but who knows… Check cells formatting. Sometimes, when there is Text format selected, the formula may not work correctly.

Comment: `sumRes = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cellCurrent, sumRes)` is orders of magnitude slower than `sumRes = sumRes + cellCurrent`

Comment: Just my 2c, but your life will be easier if you store "flag" information as actual values in a dedicated column, not as color data overlaid on an existing value: then you can use existing (non-volatile) formulas such as countif(), sumif() etc.   If you want coloring for appearance purposes then you can use Conditional Formatting, based off the "flag" column values.

Comment: As I said many times before: Colour is not data. Don't colour-code data and then try to perform calculations based on colour. That leads to exactly the problems you're facing now. Use indicators in the worksheet to classify the data. Then you can use conditional formatting to generate the colours, if needed, and you can use the indicator cells for further calculations. In many cases you wouldn't need any code at all for something like this. Bad data architecture requires complicated solutions. Keep it simple.

Comment: The cells are not set to manual calculate and the sums usually work just fine. However, when my supervisor opens the sheet, she will change some values and get #N/A. I have only noticed that #N/A appears in place of the sums when I leave the spreadsheet open overnight. Otherwise, the sums calculate just fine and find and replace fixes the issue immediately. However, my supervisor would rather I just put in manual sums for the cells that she color codes if my formula is going to require any additional steps.